# Create table with string on getdate()

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, getdate

I would like to create a table which will auto-generate a run date once an entry is added.

```
CREATE TABLE ProjectDate (
Year varchar(10)
,TotalOrders varchar(15)
,RunDate date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE())
```

What should I modify in the above statement to add a text like "Project Run On" + Run Date which is `GETDATE()` above?

This is the result that I want to have:

```
Year    TotalOrders RunDate
2005    1379    Project Run On 8/13/2017
2006    3692    Project Run On 8/13/2017
2007    12443   Project Run On 8/13/2017
2008    13951   Project Run On 8/13/2017
```

Comment: If your code works, you are not using MySQL.  I replace that tag with SQL Server.

Comment: `RunDate` as `varchar` is going to screw you if you wanted to sort projects. I have a feeling there's a better place to append static text `Run On`, possibly a procedure or program that reads this table data.

Answer (score 2):

You can put function calls as the default, so this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE ProjectDate (
    Year varchar(10),
    TotalOrders varchar(15),
    RunDate varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT CONCAT('Project Run On ', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 121))
);
```

Note:  I prefer the ISO standard format YYYY-MM-DD.

Here is a [Rextester](http://rextester.com/ATLCV79136).

Comment: Wow I have been searching for SQL fiddle alternative since quite a time.

Comment: I got the following error when I try to add the values:

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.


INSERT INTO ProjectDate (Year, TotalOrders)
VALUES (2005, 1379),(2006, 3692),(2007, 12443),(2008, 13951)

Comment: @Steve . . . That is really strange.  It works when I run it (as evidenced by the rextester link).  Have you declared `RunDate` to be `varchar`?

Comment: I just declare RunDate to varchar, but when ading value, I got this: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated. I only need the YYYY-MM-DD, not the full set including time.

Comment: @Steve . . . Include the length, as in the answer and the rextester example.

Comment: Work great! Thanks guy! :D

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to **pollute** a **USEFUL** date value by converting it into a meaningless/redundant string?

This really belongs in the presentation layer. Would it not make more sense in a query:

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,Msg = Format(RunDate,'Projec\t Run On M/dd/yyyy')
 From ProjectDate
 Where DatePart(YEAR,RunDate)=2017
```